# Does oracle spatial store arcs as clockwise or counterclockwise

Tags: oracle, spatial, oracle-spatial

To create an arc in oracle the following are used:

```
SGO_GTYPE = 2002
SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY = 1,2,2
SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY = start, center and end points
```

My question is in regards to the start, center and end points.  I am finding some conflicting information on how to determine the start and end points.  The oracle documentation mentions **counterclockwise** for polygons but the pro oracle spatial book mentions **clockwise** for arcs.  Which is the correct way to store an arc in oracle? clockwise or counterclockwise?  Thank you.

References:

[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96630/sdo_objrelschema.htm)

[Pro Oracle Book](https://books.google.com/books?id=RA1gBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=oracle%20arc%201,2,2%202002&source=bl&ots=ctVpc9JGYb&sig=JL0GKR7oBlFzOzrhUkXA4Wo1Uow&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwit36mvwanfAhVSIqwKHciIDO8Q6AEwBXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=oracle%20arc%201%2C2%2C2%202002&f=false)

Notice in the Oracle book it stores it clockwise but in the oracle documentation, everything refers to counterclockwise!

[image]